# Styling multiple types of WPF controls

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, styles

I have a stack panel with a few (different) items:

```
<StackPanel ...>
    <TextBlock ... />
    <CheckBox ... />
    <CheckBox ... />
    <Button ... />
</StackPanel>
```

I would like to apply `VerticalAlignment="Center"` to all children of the StackPanel *without having to add `VerticalAlignent="Center"` or `Style=...` to every single child*. So, I guess I want to define an implicit style which applies to the TextBlock, the CheckBoxes and the Button.

I tried adding a `<Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">` in the stack panel's resources, but (obviously) this doesn't work, since the TargetType creates an implicit x:Key of `{x:Type FrameworkElement}`, whereas TextBlock only automatically binds to Styles with an x:Key of `{x:Type TextBlock}`.

So, as far as I can see, the only options I have are: (1) create three Styles for all three types in the stack panel's resources, (2) create one style and manually bind it to all children, (3) manually set the `VerticalAlignment` option at all children. **What I want is**: (4) Create one Style and *automatically* bind it to all children of the stack panel. Is that possible? Or is there some other solution that is less redundant than (1)-(3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heinzi,

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it seems like you have a StackPanel that you want to contain a set of children.  These children you want to have a style `VerticalAlignment="Center"` but you don't want to add this property to each child.  If this is the case, I have a solution for you:

There is, however, no way to set a base object's properties and have them used in the inherited class.  So, a `FrameworkElement` has a property `VerticalAlignment`, but you can't set that directly in a style and have it applied automatically.  In my proposed solution, you do have to create a style for each object type, but you don't have to create a distinct style for each.  In my solution, you can create a "BaseStyle" then base each of your other styles on this one to get the desired result.  So you can do this:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="500">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="testing textblock" />
            <CheckBox  Content="testing check1 "/>
            <CheckBox Content="testing check2" />
            <Button Content="testing button" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Also, you can set these at an application level via `Application.xaml`.  This would mean that you only have to create these styles once, and you shouldn't need to implement them across all of your pages/screens.

I hope this helps,

### Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not as simple as I had hoped (e.g. <Style TargetType="{everything derived from FrameworkElement}">), but I understand that this is not possible and your solution is definitely an improvement to what I've had so far.